# Add anchors to Winter Bash FAQ

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, meta-faq, anchor

It would be nice to be able to link to specific questions (with their answers) in the [Winter Bash FAQ](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/faq). Especially this year, as the banner image takes [almost the entire screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilykj.png) (on my MacBook Pro 13") - it's almost impossible to see you're not on the main page. Because the frequently asked questions seem to be reused every year, it will provide a lasting benefit.